# How can I fill zeros to blank dates?

Tags: r, loops

```
dates=data.frame(table(df13$date_of_admission))
newdf=data.frame(Var1=seq(as.Date("2018/01/01"),as.Date("2021/01/31"),by="day"))

f1=numeric(length(newdf$Var1))
for (i in 1:length(newdf$Var1)) {
  for (j in 1:length(dates$Var1)) {
    if(as.Date(newdf$Var1[i])==as.Date(dates$Var1[j])){
      f1[i]=dates$Freq[j]
    }
  }
  
}

newdf$Freq=f1
```

Var1 denotes date.
In dates data frame, It consists dates and corresponding frequencies. I created newdf with specific date range. Now I want to add frequencies in dates data frame to newdf. I used above for loops to do that job. Since I need to put zero for frequency in newdf which is not in dates data frame, I used those for loops. This code works well but take some time to run. So I need a method do to this without for loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **dplyr** join method to do so:

```
library(dplyr)
dates <- data.frame(table(df13$date_of_admission))
newdf <- data.frame(Var1=seq(as.Date("2018/01/01"),as.Date("2021/01/31"),by="day"))

result <- left_join(newdf, dates, by = "Var1")
```

With out data sample, I can't be sure this works. The formats of **Var1** in both dataframes must be the same (if not, mutate the column format as Dates).

Comment: @MigaraDevinda As you're new, don't forget to validate the answer ;)

Comment: Okay. I'm sorry for that. Actually I'm new to this platform.